# jQuery how to find last HTML element stored in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a page that has a bunch of sibling elements. I'm doing several things with the elements. The 1st thing I've done successfully was stored the sibling elements in tables according to what year they fall under. Each year has a bunch of div's, p's and hr's under it. For the very last div of each section year I have to take the HR tag away. I tried using the `.last()` method but it's not working. Can someone help me without changing my entire code.

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
var togglerHeaders = $("h2.toggler");
    for (i = 2; i < togglerHeaders.length; i++) {
  var currentH2Element = togglerHeaders[i];
  var siblingsofH2 = $(currentH2Element).nextUntil("h2.toggler");
    $(siblingsofH2).wrapAll("<table></table>");
        $("hr").last().css("display", "none");
    } // line ends for loop
    togglerHeaders.slice(0,2).removeClass('toggler');
    $(".toggler").next().hide();
$(".toggler").click(function(){
  $(".toggler").next().toggleClass();
});
}); 
</script>
```

After I wrap the siblings from the present H2 to the next H2 into a table, I'm trying to target that table to get the last H2 in that table and set it to `display:none`.

HTML

*The html represents once the siblings are actually in a table and now I'm trying to remove only the last HR tag for each table.

```
<table>   
<div class="box">
<h3>Roses</h3> 
<p>Red, White, Black</p>
</hr>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Tulips</h3> 
<p>White, Pink, Yellow</p>
</hr>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Dandelions</h3> 
<p>Yellow</p>
</hr>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Lillies</h3> 
<p>Pink, White, Blue</p>
</hr>
</div>
</table>
<table>   
<div class="box">
<h3>Apples</h3> 
<p>Red, Yellow, Granny Smith</p>
</hr>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Carrots</h3> 
<p>Orange, Rainbow, Baby</p>
</hr>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Lettuce</h3> 
<p>Green leaf, Red leaf, Romaine</p>
</hr>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Peppers</h3> 
<p>Green, Red, Yellow</p>
</hr>
</div>
</table>
<table>   
<div class="box">
<h3>Dogs</h3> 
<p>Jack Russell, Poodle, Pit bull</p>
</hr>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Fish</h3> 
<p>gold, rainbow, salmon</p>
</hr>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Birds</h3> 
<p>humming bird, bluebird, robin</p>
</hr>
</div>
<div class="box">
<h3>Butterflies</h3> 
<p>Black, Yellow, White</p>
</hr>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid.... How is a div a child of a table element?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is you are using `table` but not using `table`'s tags (`tr`,`td`, etc). That is why it is going outside of the table. Just replace `table` tag with `div`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var togglerHeaders = $("h2.toggler");
  for (i = 2; i < togglerHeaders.length; i++) {
    var currentH2Element = togglerHeaders[i];
    var siblingsofH2 = $(currentH2Element).nextUntil("h2.toggler");
    $(siblingsofH2).wrapAll("<div class='container'></div>");
  } // line ends for loop
  togglerHeaders.slice(0, 2).removeClass('toggler');
  $(".toggler").next().hide();
  $(".toggler").click(function() {
    $(".toggler").next().toggleClass();
  });

  var tables = $(".container");

  tables.each(function(index, table) {
    console.log($(table).find("div").last());
    //$(table).find("hr").last().replaceWith("*".repeat(80)); 
    $(table).find("hr").last().hide(); 
  })
});
```

Comment: But how do I get it to do it for each table. When I tried it still wouldn't work

Comment: Just change this `  $("hr").last().css("display", "none");` piece of code to the above one.

Comment: Ok I found the solution, but the problem is why you are using `table` tag? That is the problem here. `div` blocks going outside of the table that's why it is not selecting any `child` elements.

Comment: I'm using it like this because I'm actually following the HTML of a previous page and I have to tweak it. Some things I can change, some I can't. It's not my original code.

Comment: You're code looks really good I just don't understand what's going on. I need something I can be able to comprehend. Not as advanced as I

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/MrNCQ8h this is what is going on when you open source code. Blocks are going outside of table

Comment: So you're saying it's no true way to target it because the elements are going outside the table?

Comment: @Aishah91, right. You can't actually select last `hr` element from each table

Comment: Darn it. Ok but the code you gave finds a way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183027/discussion-between-tim-ggwp-and-aishah91).